# Rewrite $y(x) = \int_0^x (x - \tau)y(\tau) d\tau + x^3$ as an ODE in the form of $u'(t) = F(t, u(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, lipschitz-functions, integral-equations

$$y(x) = \int_0^x (x - \tau)y(\tau) d\tau + x^3$$

$$y'(x) = x y(x) + 3x^2$$

$$y''(x) =  y(x) + xy'(x) + 6x = y(x) + x^2 y(x) + 3x^2 + 6x$$

Let

$$u = (u_1, u_2) = (y, y')$$

$$u' = (u_1', u_2') = (y', y'')$$

So we get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}u_1'\\ u_2'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ -1&x\:+\frac{2}{x}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ u_2\end{pmatrix}$$

But apparently, this cannot be the right solution, because our matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ -1&x\:+\frac{2}{x}\end{pmatrix}$ is not Lipschitz for $x=0$ (which is the other part of our exercise to prove that it's Lipschitz for $x=0$). The reason it's not Lipschitz is because the matrix norm would be equal to infinity

So where is my mistake?

Comment: I have problem with your first derivative and get $y'(x)=\int_0^xy(t)dt+3x^2$

Answer (score 2):

$$y(x) = \int_0^x (x - \tau)y(\tau) d\tau + x^3$$
Apply [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Example_3):
$$y'(x) = \int_0^x y(\tau) d\tau + 3x^2$$
$$y''(x) = y(x) + 6x$$

Comment: And how can I transform this into a matrix equation?